# update wordpress3.3 to wordpress4.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I have update wordpress3.3 to wordpress4.1 give this type of error.

wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks.

how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: prabhat singh please refer this link and let me know if this working `https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_enqueue_script-was-called-incorrectly-7`

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating plugins one by one and check if this error goes away. I had the similar issue. When I deactivated BWP Google XML Sitemaps plugin, it went away.